# Visual Studio Toolbox - Data not containing Chart

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2022 .NET 6.0 Windows Form.

I want to add a chart, however the chart option is not displayed, I have tried resetting the toolbox and right clicking to add it, however it says that it is already in place. I have restarted the VS multiple times but I am still without the chart option.

Is this a simple fix or is there something greater at work here.

Many thanks,
K

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has deprecated a lot of components between versions; the chart control is one of these.

The GitHub winforms repository has a discussion about this topic.
https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/discussions/6163